# At which cases is it necessary to specify trampoline classes in Pybind11 bindings code?

Tags: c++, pybind11

According to an example in Pybind11 [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#combining-virtual-functions-and-inheritance), we have two classes, namely `Animal` and `Dog`. `Animal` contains some virtual and pure virtual methods and the `Dog` class implements/overrides them. Based on this example, two other trampoline classes are created (`PyAnimal` & `PyDog`) to make these classes constructible. But, the documentation adds that:

> ... but in order to allow python code to inherit properly from Dog, we
> also need a trampoline class for Dog that overrides both the added
> bark() method and the go() and name() methods inherited from Animal
> (even though Dog doesn’t directly override the name() method):

This part of the documentation is not clear to me. What I do not understand is that in the `Dog` and `Animal` example, suppose that my Python code **will never inherit these two classes**. In other words, my Python code simply instantiates the `Dog` class and calls its methods. So, in this case, do I need a trampoline for `Animal`? Or I simply need a trampoline class for the `Dog` only? Or maybe a simple binding code for `Dog`, without any trampoline classes?

I am asking this question because in my project I am having lots of interfaces and abstract classes like `Intfc1`, `Intfc2`, ... and `Abst1`, `Abst2`, ... and so on. In addition, lots of concrete classes are realizing/inheriting these interfaces or abstract classes. Moreover, suppose that **my Python code, will never realize/inherit these abstract classes or interfaces**. But the python code simply initializes the concrete classes and use them.

Now, the main question is: should I add the trampoline classes and the bindings code for `Intfc1`, `Intfc2`, ... and `Abst1`, `Abst2`, ...? Or I only need to add the trampoline and binding for my concrete classes? Or I only need to add the bindings for my concrete classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will answer your question [PYBIND11_OVERRIDE](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#c.PYBIND11_OVERRIDE)

> Macro to populate the virtual method in the trampoline class. **This macro tries to look up the method from the Python side**, deals with the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) and necessary argument conversions to call this method and return the appropriate type. This macro should be used if the method name in C and in Python are identical. See Overriding virtual functions in Python for more information.

if you don't inherit from the c++ class on python side then you don't need a trampoline class, it only exists to allow you to inherit and override its methods on python side.

---

Pybind11 requires you to define wrappers for any return or argument type for any c++ function that can be called from python.

In order to call a Function that exposes an abstract class `Animal`

```
Animal* MakeDog();
py::class_<Animal>(module, "Animal")
```

You only need the wrapper for the abstract `Animal`, you don't need the wrapper for the concrete type `Dog`.

if you are only calling functions that expose `Dog` you only need a wrapper for `Dog` to exist, you don't need Pybind11 to know an `Animal` class even exists.

```
Dog* MakeDog();
py::class_<Dog>(module, "Dog")
```

Lastly if you have any function that takes `Animal` and you want to pass a `Dog` to it from python then you need to wrap both and you need pybind11 to know of their inheritance for the cast to happen.

```
void do_bark(Animal*);
py::class_<Dog, Animal>(module, "Dog")
```

Comment: OK, got it. Then coming back to my original Q, when binding a class, is it necessary to first have the binding code for its parent abstract class (or parent interface)? Or I can simply bind my class without having any binding code for my parent abstract class or interface?

Comment: @TonySalimi if you have a factory method `Animal* CreateDog();` you need a wrapper for `Animal` for Pybind11 to represent it on python land, even if `Animal` is an abstract class, and in this example you don't need a wrapper for `Dog`, unless a c++ function takes or returns a pointer to `Dog` and you want to call it from python side, if you structure your code correctly you don't need wrappers for your concrete classes, only your abstract ones.

Comment: Got it. Suppose that I only have `Dog* CreateDog();`. So, it means that I have to bind only the `Dog` class. In this case, should I introduce the `Animal` as the parent class during the binding code of `Dog`, i.e. `py::class_<Dog, Animal>(module, "Dog")`? Or I can have the binding code of `Dog` without mentioning `Animal`, like this: `py::class_<Dog>(module, "Dog")`

Comment: @TonySalimi if any function in your interface takes or returns a pointer or reference to `Animal` then you need a wrapper for `Animal` too, and you need `py::class_<Dog, Animal>(module, "Dog")` so pybind11 can do the casting, so just create.

Comment: So, it means that if **NO** function in my API takes or returns a pointer or reference to `Animal` then I can bind `Dog` like: `py::class_<Dog>(module, "Dog")` without mentioning `Animal` as the parent of `Dog`? Am I right?

Comment: @TonySalimi you are right, it is only needed for casts at the interface boundary.